# How to avoid Shell Injection with a path variable and wait for command exist?

Tags: python, shell, code-injection

I need to read the exit of a command (then I have to wait for it in sync way):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ls ~', shell=True)
```

My problem is a path like this:

```
~/testing/;xterm;/blabla
```

How could I sanitize that string from user (allowing special characters from his language)?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ls ~/testing/;xterm;/blabla', shell=True) # This will launch xterm
```

I found escapeshellcmd in PHP, but I didn't find anything in Python.

PS: It's not a duplicate of this:

- Because it's the complete path, [not the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python).
- And [I read the `os.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939120/sanitizing-a-file-path-in-python) and I didn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

=======

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a list instead of a string. And remove `shell=True` to make the command are not run by shell. (You need to expand `~` yourself using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser))

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ls', os.path.expanduser('~') + '/testing/;xterm;/blabla'])
```

Side note: If you want to get list of filenames, you'd better to use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) instead:

```
filelist = os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/testing/;xterm;/blabla')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found this problem: without the shell=True, I can't get the exit of the command, filelist is always empty.

Comment: @costales, It's weird. Could you try this? `filelist = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'testing', ';xterm;', 'blabla'))`

Comment: I would use check_call unless you want to ignore non zero exit  status

Comment: @falsetru, yes that is what I meant.

Comment: @falsetru: Thanks a lot! the os library is solving my issue :)